# Blocking HTTP clients which request certain URLs repeatedly

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, hacking

I run a website on Windows Server 2008 R2. Looking through the IIS logs, I have noticed that there are some IP addresses repeatedly requesting certain URLs (such as for example /mysql/phpmyadmin/main.php, /phpadmin/main.php) which do not exist, as the site is entirely served off of ASP.NET. They are obviously fishing for known vulnerabilities.

My question is, are there any firewall or other tools (Windows built-in or commercial) that allow me to block those IP addresses which request certain URLs multiple times?

Comment: In fact this is probably a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/64711/can-iis-automatically-block-ips-based-on-certain-queries

Answer (score 0):

From what I hear, you can use [UrlScan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650), kind of like mod_security for apache.